# Risks of editing IL and recompiling the DLL

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a huge business silverlight project in production and I need to edit a hardcoded string in the application.

At the moment , the version of the application is different(older) than the version I'm currently developing so I can't recompile the application.
Thus , the only way of editing would be to use net reflector to decompile and edit the right offset and recompile the dll.

I'm wondering , what are the risks of doing this , could something go wrong or some code to be corrupted?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I've done this in rare circumstances where source was long lost. It works well, just make sure you include all of the resources, and if your project is strong name signed, make sure you have the original key to resign it.

Comment: Assuming huge business projects are in source control, couldn't you just get the right version of the sources?

Comment: The source control was updated with the version I'm currently working on ..so ..I can't..but after all ..I've manged to change the IL and recompile the dll through net reflector.